# How to diagnose myopia in a 2-year old?

Tags: eye, toddler

Is there an exam that clearly diagnoses a child myopia level without the need of this child's feedback (as he is not going to give it, given his age (2))?

Like, is there a laser exam or something like that which can give a precise measurement?

I know I can get him to an ophthalmologist, and I will, but I just want to be well informed before hand to avoid not giving him an adequate diagnoses and hinder the treatment we might use.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Caio

Answer (score 3):

Refractive errors can be detected by using an ophthalmoscope. To get an accurate measurement you can do streak retinoscopy.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16020274